# Вывод всех ключей из json

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

```
json_string = """
{
    "researcher": {
        "name": "Ford Prefect",
        "species": "Betelgeusian",
        "relatives": [
            {
                "name": "Zaphod Beeblebrox",
                "species": "Betelgeusian"
            }
        ]
    }
}
"""
```

Есть json файл, ответ сверху. Надо, чтобы вывод в консоль был следующим:

```
researcher.name: "Ford Prefect",
researcher.species: "Betelgeusian",
researcher.relatives[0].name: "Zaphod Beeblebrox",
researcher.relatives[0].species: "Betelgeusian"
```

UPD:

Как сделать, чтобы был вывод как я описал выше на языке Python? Скрипт снизу упирается в первый ключ.

```
json_data = json.loads(json_string)

for i in json_data:
    print(i)
```

Comment: И в чём проблема пройтись в цикле?

Comment: Надо, так надо. А сложность то в чем. Другими словами: какой вопрос то у вас?

Comment: @GrAnd или сразу запихнуть в словарь при помощи модуля `json`

Comment: Обновил, забыл вопрос поставить.

Comment: @Boro8ey, `for i in json_data: print(i)` - это все, что вы смогли написать сами??

Comment: @MaxU `for i in json_data:  for a in json_data[i]:  for s in json_data[s]:  print(s)
 `, но тот ловит ошибку. Через while у меня не получилось.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В лоб через рекурсию:

```
def print_json(data, path=[]):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        for k,v in data.items():
            print_json(v, path+[k])
    elif isinstance(data, list):
        for i,v in enumerate(data):
            print_json(v, path[:-1]+[f'{path[-1]}[{i}]'])
    elif isinstance(data, str):
        print(f'{".".join(path)}: "{data}",')
    else:
        print(f'{".".join(path)}: {data},')

print_json(json.loads(json_string))
```